# How to get server datetime in JS?

Tags: javascript, api, hmac

I am implementing HMAC authorization in my SPA, and I am using current datetime as part of my hash to ensure that tokens can time out. Obviously client's machine can have any datetime set and for this to be correctly checked on the server, it has to match server's date & time. What is the best practice for this?

I can currently think of a few ways that would work:

1. Before every request, send an API request to retrieve current server's date & time (not prefered method as that would essentially double the number of ajax requests).
2. On page load, send an API request to retrieve current server's date & time, and save the client's date and time as well. For any further ajax requests, compare the current time to client's time and add the same difference to the saved initial server time to essentially get the server time.
3. Same as #2, but instead of initial API request, embed the datetime in the HTML page itself.

Is there any better way that I am not thinking of? Any #2 & #3 caveats (with timezones, DST etc.) that I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess thats why I wrote the first comment. If any information is added by the client (like timezone or a date stamp) you've introduced something insecure; it looks like you overlooked this. A UTC date/time should be included in the payload secured by the HMAC. The client should be checking this to know if the token needs refreshing exactly the same way as the server checks it.

Comment: @BlueWater86 "A UTC date/time should be included in the payload secured by the HMAC" - I'm a little confused, that date/time has to come from somewhere, that is precisely what my question is about? The client does not need to do any of the checking as a unique token is generated for each request.

Comment: If the server is going to validate it, doesn't the server need to generate it in the first place? ie, using it's own date/time and mashup. Might help us if you fleshed out how the tokens are generated, used and checked.

Comment: Not sure where the previous comments went but they still stand. A trusted third party should be issuing a token which is signed after the user is successfully challenged. Your SPA should be relaying this to your API. If your SPA wants to perform some kind of client side expiry message; it should inspect the payload and compare the current UTC date to the tokens UTC date.